# Trying to create a method to control font size. Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to create a font size control, the idea is that the user can change the font size of the entire app through the Slider, drag this bar and adjust it like 14px, 16px, 18px, 20px... minimum and maximum. I also read that the best way to make the changes on several screens will be using the provider, what is your opinion on this choice?
This is the starting code.

```
class Settings extends StatefulWidget {
  const Settings({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Settings> createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {

  double _rating = 20;

  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersive);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        elevation: 0,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue[900]),
        title: const Text(
          'Settings',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          ListTile(
            title: Text('Button'),
            trailing: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_forward_ios,
              color: Colors.blue,
            ),
            onTap: () {
              showModalBottomSheet<void>(
                  context: context,
                  builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return Container(
                      height: 200,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Center(
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                              child: Text(
                                'Change font',
                                style: TextStyle(

                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Slider(
                              value: _rating,
                              min: 0,
                              max: 28,
                              divisions: 4,
                              label: _rating.round().toString(),
                              onChanged: (newRating) {
                                setState(() => _rating = newRating);
                              },
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a provider example it might help you

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
 ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SliderValue()),
  ], child: MyApp()));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
   title: 'Flutter Demo',
   theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    ),
    home: SizableText(),
  );
}
}

class SliderValue with ChangeNotifier {
double _value = 5;

double get value => _value;

void increment(double val) {
  _value = val;
  notifyListeners();
 }
}

class SizableText extends StatefulWidget {
const SizableText({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
State<SizableText> createState() => _SizableTextState();
}

class _SizableTextState extends State<SizableText> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(title: Text("AppBar")),
    body: Center(
     child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(5.0)),
              boxShadow: [
                new BoxShadow(
                    color: Colors.black38,
                    offset: new Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                    blurRadius: 10)
              ]),
          child: new Slider(
            value: context.watch<SliderValue>().value,
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white,
            onChanged: (double s) {
              context.read<SliderValue>().increment(s);
            },
            divisions: 10,
            min: 0.0,
            max: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text1(text: 'Hello'),
        Text1(text: 'Hi'),
      ],
    ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

class Text1 extends StatelessWidget {
Text1({this.text});
final String? text;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Text(text ?? '',
    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10 * context.watch<SliderValue>().value));
 }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I just have a question the app I'm creating is basically text how do I make the size control change all screens?

Comment: It has 15 screens of text.

Comment: you can use it on other screens too like i showed in eg use context.watch<SliderValue>().value for getting value of slider in other screens

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Basic idea is stored `fonsize` value in somewhere that `Text` can reach, **state management** will update the value of `fonsize` and notify to theres subscription. Im not using provider so im use an other **state management** is [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) to do this.

```dart
// ignore_for_file: prefer_const_constructors_in_immutables

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class HomeController extends GetxController {
  var fontSizeObx = RxDouble(12);

  setFontsize(double value) => fontSizeObx.value = value;
}

class HomeRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  HomeRoute({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final controller = Get.put(HomeController());

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Obx(
          () => Column(
            children: [
              Text(
                'Hello world',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: controller.fontSizeObx.value),
              ),
              Slider(
                value: controller.fontSizeObx.value,
                onChanged: controller.setFontsize,
                divisions: 10,
                min: 10.0,
                max: 100.0,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
double _value = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(title: Text("AppBar")),
     body: Center(
     child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.blue,
              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(new Radius.circular(5.0)),
              boxShadow: [new BoxShadow(color: Colors.black38, 
              offset: new Offset(0.0, 2.0), blurRadius: 10)]),
          child: new Slider(
            value: _value,
            activeColor: Colors.white,
            inactiveColor: Colors.white,
            onChanged: (double s) {
              setState(() {
                _value = s;
              });
            },
            divisions: 10,
            min: 0.0,
            max: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
          Text("Hello World", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10 * _value)),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi Priyaank thanks for your contribution, I used the example you showed but the slider bar does not control the font size and when I used it in a text outside the widget it reports an error of "Invalid constant value.". The slider bar should control the font size of the texts.